# Rails .each except if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, if-statement

I have a rails table called Movies. Movies are being collected and saved from an API which means that some movies may have a release_date and some may not.

All Movies are being displayed on the home page and they are sorted by `{|t| - t.release_date.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i}`

```
<% @movies.sort_by{|t| - t.release_date.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i}.each do |movie| %>

<% movie.title %>
<% movie.release_date.strftime("%Y") %>

<% end %>
```

So this code works fine but only as long as the returned movies have a release date. If they don't have a release date assigned, it gives me the following error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass):
```

But im only getting this error if the movie has no release_date.
So how can i add an exception to only display films WITH a release_date, where using strftime would no longer be a problem.

I've tried

```
<% unless movie.release_date.blank? %>

<% @movies.sort_by{|t| - t.release_date.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i}.each do |movie| %>

<% @movie.title %>
<% @movie.release_date.strftime("%Y") %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work as it gives an `undefined method for 'movie'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `reject` to reject nil release_date like follows:

```
<% @movies.reject{ |m| m.release_date.nil? } %>
```

Another problem is you are using the variable `movie` as instance variable `@movie` within your `each` block.

Try:

```
<% @movies.reject{ |m| m.release_date.nil? }.sort_by{|t| - t.release_date.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i}.each do |movie| %>

<% movie.title %>
<% movie.release_date.strftime("%Y") %>

<% end %>
```

**Update:**

And yes, as pointed by @NicolasGarnil in his answer, it's better to do these in SQL side than in ruby side.  Select only the required records and let database do the sorting.  So you could update your code to be something like:

In controller:

```
@movies = Movie.where('release_date is not null').order('release_date desc');
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>

<% movie.title %>
<% movie.release_date.strftime("%Y") %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm trying it in production mode now as that is where i got the error.

Yes I dont actually have it as <% @movie %> in my code, I was just writing it directly into StackO so I wasnt in the Rails Mindset ^_^, edited it.

Comment: @PMP, in that case you can just add `reject{ |m| m.release_date.nil? }`

Comment: @PMP, I should not forget to advise you that modifying directly in production is highly discouraged!

Comment: No no i didn't mean I edited it in production, I just pointed out that I had added the code to my text editor, checked it in dev mode to make sure there were no errors and then add it to heroku. The reason for this is because my database is very different in dev mode then it is in production mode, so the error I was getting was in prod. mode only and not in dev. mode.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons you should not be using ruby to sort your records. This should be done at a database level.

You should first ensure that the release_date values are persisted in an appropriate format and then just use `Movie.order("release_date desc")`. Records with null values will be placed at the end of the results.

Comment: First, using `@movies.sort("release_date desc")` (which was your first answer) doesn't work as it gives me _wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)_

Comment: And Secondly using `Movie.sort("release_date DESC")` in the controller, I presume, gives me this error _undefined method `sort' for_

Comment: In rails 4 I think you can also append `.where.not(release_date:nil)` to do the filtering on the db level also.